# Filtering a CUBESET using a different variable without hierarchies

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, excel-2010, mdx, powerpivot

I'm trying to produce a `cubeset` that only returns members that correspond to another field in my Powerpivot dataset. Because my organisation is so behind we're using an old version of Powerpivot (SQL Server 2008r2 version) that doesn't allow for Hierarchies etc. so I can't use that functionality; I've been trying to use the `FILTER` `mdx` function but can't get it to work.

In the example below, `[Level 1]` and `[Level 2]` are are product groups, with 2 being below one. I'm trying to return all members of [Level 2] that correspond to [Level 1].[Product 1]:

```
    =CUBESET("Powerpivot Data",
    "FILTER([Table].[Level 2].[All].Members,
     [Table].[Level 1].[All].CurrentMember='Product 1')","Caption")
```

This just returns a #N/A error in excel. If anyone has a way to get this result then please shout!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a string error - do you need to double up the speach marks around Product 1?:

```
"FILTER([Table].[Level 2].[All].Members,
     [Table].[Level 1].[All].CurrentMember=''Product 1'')"
```

The above is not the problem.

The problem is that your condition is not valid mdx `[Table].[Level 1].[All].CurrentMember='Product 1'` you should be using the `Descendants` function for the use case you've presented:

```
"Descendants([Table].[Level 1].[Product 1],[Table].[Level 2])"
```